# How to empty the history of search in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

How can I empty the history of search and replace tool in Texstudio? I have around 100 words searched which makes it difficult for me to look for a word on the list. Please see the picture below

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The previously searched words are stored in the `texstudio.ini` file. The location of this file depends on your operating system, on mac it is located in

```
~/.config/textstudio/
```

Close texstudio and open the file a text editor and search for `Search\Find%20History`. You can see a comma separated list of previously search words. Delete whatever words you don't want to keep. If you now reopen texstudio it should use the cleaned up list.